# Google glass: Scroll up and down thanks to swipe_left and swipe_right

Tags: java, android, google-glass

Is there a way that i could handle **scroll up** and **down** in my activities thank's to **Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT**(which will trigger the scroll up action)  and **Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT**(which will trigger the scroll down action) ?

Any piece of code will be much appreciate...

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch

Comment: Yes i already use this but i don't know how i could write the right code to make my app work the way i want...

Answer (score 0):

The following code is basically copy pasted from the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch#detecting_activity-level_gestures). Define the `scrollUp` and `scrollDown` methods as you wish.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector();
  }

  @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mGestureDetector != null) {
            return mGestureDetector.onMotionEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

  private GestureDetector createGestureDetector() {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    gestureDetector.setBaseListener(new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
        if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
          scrollUp();
          return true;
        } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT) {
          scrollDown();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }

    return gestureDetector;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! but this is precisely my issue: how to define scrollUp() and scrollDown()... I have search an easy way to implement those methods but i didn't succeed